# jquery command is executed irregularly

Tags: jquery, debugging

I have just written my first jQuery code and it works partially. Completely it works only on the second click. My goal is that when you click on the filter digital, the thumbnail to digital is displayed. This thumbnail has the class ".digital" and for print the class ".print". The filters have the same name as ID.

I have written the following code for this:

```
<script>
$('.project-thumbnail').hide();
</script>

<script>
    $('#digital').click(function(){
          $('.project-thumbnail').hide();
          $('.digital').show();
        });
        
        $('#print').click(function(){
          $('.project-thumbnail').hide();
          $('.print').show();
        });
        
        $('#branding').click(function(){
          $('.project-thumbnail').hide();
        });
<script>
```

And this is the test page: [Link](https://schmid-wolf-2nd.webflow.io/projekte)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Can you describe exactly what does not work?

Comment: @dave-s For example, when you click from print to digital, thumbnails from print are still displayed as those from digital. The best thing is to try the link above.

Comment: I have looked at the example but I'm not sure what problem you have.  If I load the page and click on digital or click on print they both appear to work fine as far as I can tell.  If I reload the page and click on branding first then the entire list disappears and if I click on digital or branding at that point then the list comes back.  There must be other javascript besides what you are showing in the question that is removing items from the list, no?  If you can describe exactly the steps you take, what you see and what you expect, it would help.

Comment: Can you provide a *complete* [mcve]?   Include only enough html/css/js to *recreate the problem* in a snippet in your question.  Using test-based images/text-divs will also help as we don't know if the images shown are *meant* to be for digital/print etc as they're just random images to us.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you very much for taking the time. I have followed your advice. It sounds very logical but unfortunately the same bug still exists.

Comment: Your next step is to recreate the issue here, in the question via an [edit] and click `[<>]`.  Include just  enough to recreate the issue.   Shouldn't be hard to fix after that step - with example code showing the fix rather than a vague "add this".

Comment: @freedomn-m Unfortunately, I can't reproduce everything. That would take far too much time. I built the website with webflow. I have a feeling that, as DaveS said, another javascript code will lead to problems. I tried with the $.noConflict(); method, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: You should be able to provide *enough* of an example to reproduce the issue, not *everything*.   Otherwise how can we confirm that it will work when we provide a solution?

Comment: I think I see the problem. You would have to play the jQuery at the very end of all the scripts. Because it only doesn't work when new projects are loaded, for example.